Derivation of Differential Equation of a Simple Pendulum
This pretty much a simple question and i seem to be making a dumb error here, but nonetheless I can't get the correct answer for the general equation of a pendulum which is :$$\ddot\theta=-\frac{g}{L}sin\theta$$This is my proof of the same equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot\theta^2l^2-mgl=-mglcos\theta$$$$\dot\theta^2=\frac{2g}{l}(1-cos\theta)$$
Assuming small angles approximations:$$\dot\theta^2=\frac{g}{l}\theta^2$$

This was using Energy conversations at A and C (or B and C)

Draw a force diagram, use Newton’s laws, and don’t use the small angle approximation.

Actually, you may use the small angle approximation, but this involves switching an $x$ or $y$ variable into the angle variable

You have a sign error in your expression for the total energy. It should read $$E=\frac{m \ell^2 \dot{\theta}^2}{2}+\underbrace{mg \ell (1 - \cos \theta)}_{V(\theta)} = \;\rm const. \tag{1} \label{1}$$ You can easily check the correctness of $V(\theta)$ by inserting, say, $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi/2$, finding  $V(\pi/2)=mgl \gt V(0)=0$, as it should be. As eq. \eqref{1} can be rewritten in the form $$ \frac{1}{2}\,\dot{\theta}^2= \frac{g}{ \ell}\,  \cos{\theta} + \;\text{constant terms}, \tag{2} \label{2}$$ the equation of motion can be recovered by differentiating eq. \eqref{2} with respect to time, being left as an easy homework exercise.
Remark: It is in fact easier to write down the equation of motion directly, without using the detour via energy conservation. Simply consider the force component acting  on the mass point in the direction of its movement.

The total energy $~E~$ is:
$$ E=\frac 12 \,m\,L^2\dot\theta^2-m\,g\,L\,\cos(\theta)=\rm constant $$
form here for a small angle $~\theta~$
$$ E_L=\frac 12 \,m\,L^2\dot\theta^2-m\,g\,L+\,\frac 12\,m\,g\,L\,\theta^2=\rm constant $$
thus the equation of motion
$$\dot E_L=m\,L^2\,\ddot\theta+m\,g\,L\,\theta=0\quad ,\dot\theta\ne 0$$
$$\ddot\theta+\frac gL\,\theta=0$$
these equation is equal to your equation of motion for a small angle $~\theta$

The answers given before me are an exact derivation and are completely true. However while just looking at my equation for 15 mins i found that my proof was correct and all i was left to do was differentiate both sides with time. This is as follows :$$\frac{d}{dt}\dot\theta^2=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{2g}{l}(1-cos\theta)$$ $$\Rightarrow \ddot\theta=\frac{g}{l}(sin\theta)$$
